# Javascript if / else statement on screen size

Tags: javascript, navigation, conditional-statements, overlay, slide

I'm new to Javascript and have spent about three hours looking for help on this and I cannot find anything that is specific to me.

I am designing a sliding Navigation that when viewed on a Desktop the Navigation overlay slides from left to 100% width of the screen. But when on tablet / mobile it slides down from the top to 100% of the height of the device.

Thank you so much!

```js
        /* Open Nav */
    function openNav() {
      
     if  (screen.width >= 768) {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
     } else {
     document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%"; 
     }
    }
    
    
     
    /* Close Nav */
    function closeNav() {
      
     if (screen.width >= 768) {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
     } else {
     document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
     }
    }
```

```css
        /****************************** OVERLAY MENU START ***********************/
    
    .overlay {
        /* Height & width depends on how you want to reveal the overlay (see JS below) */   
        height: 100%;
     min-height: 500px;
     width: 100%;
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1000; /* Sit on top */
        left: 0;
     top: 0;
        background-color: #000000;
        overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
        transition: 0.4s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in or slide down the overlay (height or width, depending on reveal) */
    }
    
    /* Position the content inside the overlay */
    .overlay-content {
        width: 100%; /* 100% width */
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
        text-align: center; /* Centered text/links */
    }
    
    /* The navigation links inside the overlay */
    .overlay a {
        padding: 22px;
     font-family: 'gothammedium', Arial, sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 16px;
     text-transform:uppercase;
     letter-spacing: 3px;
        color: #ffffff;
        display: block; /* Display block instead of inline */
        transition: 0.3s; /* Transition effects on hover (color) */
     text-align:center;
    }
    
    /* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
    .overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
        color: #292929;
     text-decoration:none;
     transition: 0.3s; /* Transition effects on hover (color) */
    }
    
    /* Position the logo (top) */
    .overlay a.logo img {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     margin-top:45px;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     width: 35px;
     height: 40px;
    }
    
    /* Position the close button (bottom) */
    .overlay a.closebtn img {
        position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     left:0;
     right:0;
     margin-bottom: 50px;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     width: 25px;
     height: 25px;
    }
    
    .overlay .main_menu {
     position:absolute;
     top:30%;
     bottom: 70%;
     left:0;
     right:0;
     display:block;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    .menu_link {
     text-align:center;
     
    }
    
    .current_page {
     white-space: nowrap;
     color: #292929 !important;
     text-decoration:none;
    }
    
    /****************************** OVERLAY MENU FINISH ***********************/
```

```html
<div id="btns">
<button onClick="openNav();">Open</button>
</div>
<!-- Overlay content -->  
        <div id="myNav" class="overlay" style="width:0px;">  
                <div class="overlay-content">
                        <a class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                            
                            <!--Website Menu-->
                            <div class="main_menu">
                                <a class="menu_link current_page" href="#">work</a>
                                <a class="menu_link" href="#">about</a>
                                <a class="menu_link" href="#">contact</a>
                            </div>    
                            <!--Website Menu End-->
                            
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">
                        <img src="images/burger-nav-close.png" alt="burger-nav"></a>
                </div>
        </div>
        <!--Overlay End-->
```

I think that is all the code that you will need. Let me know if you need anymore :) Again, thank you!

Comment: Are you triggering this code anywhere ?

Comment: You should update both `width` and `height` in all your cases. Currently, you update only the one that you think is relevant, but there would be cases that are not covered by this.

Comment: And what do you expect? Only horizontal sliding on the both?

Comment: I would like horizontal sliding on Desktop / Laptops, but smaller than this for it to be vertical sliding.

Answer (score 0):

You should use of @media annotation in CSS.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /*For mobile phones*/
    #myNav {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I wouldn't use javascript at all?

Comment: you can do this by css also, but you want use java-script, you should get height and width of device then apply it on close and open function.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not following, so I would put a height in my Javascript? I'm very confused. I've added the code you provided into my CSS but it isnt working, when my site is on mobile the overlay navigation is still sliding out from the side (which is how it should be on desktop. ) instead of down.

My Navigation works perfectly on Desktop just not on Mobile/tablet devices.